# Android app crashes on launching in emulator

Tags: java, android

I am using viewpager to create a book app . My app crashes on launch . I have read the log but it is difficult for to find the mistake i am doing . Below is my log from logcat and Code of ViewPager . Help me to fix this problem

```
 package com.example.alan.sunshine;

import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
   ViewPager viewPager;
    CustomeSwipeAdapter customeSwipeAdapter;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        viewPager= (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
        customeSwipeAdapter=new CustomeSwipeAdapter(this);

        viewPager.setAdapter(customeSwipeAdapter);

    }
}
```

---

```
package com.example.alan.sunshine;

import android.content.Context;
import android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;

/**
 * Created by Alan on 6/18/2017.
 */

class CustomeSwipeAdapter extends PagerAdapter {
    private Context ctx;
    private LayoutInflater infalter;
    private  String[] MyContent= {"Waqar Alam","shubham","BookAPP"};
    public  CustomeSwipeAdapter(Context ctx){
        this.ctx= ctx;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return MyContent.length;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
        return (view==(LinearLayout)object);
    }

    @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
        infalter = (LayoutInflater) ctx.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View item_View = infalter.inflate(R.layout.swipe_activity,container,false);

        TextView txview = (TextView) item_View.findViewById(R.id.page_count);
        txview.setText(position);

        container.addView(item_View);

        return item_View;
    }

    @Override
    public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
        container.removeView ((LinearLayout)object);
        super.destroyItem(container, position, object);
    }

}
```

**Logcat**

```
  not find method android.view.Window$Callback.onWindowStartingActionMode, referenced from method android.support.v7.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.onWindowStartingActionMode
    06-20 16:19:10.765 1042-1042/com.example.alan.sunshine W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve interface method 17048: Landroid/view/Window$Callback;.onWindowStartingActionMode (Landroid/view/ActionMode$Callback;I)Landroid/view/ActionMode;
    06-20 16:19:10.765 1042-1042/com.example.alan.sunshine D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x72 at 0x0002
    06-20 16:19:10.765 1042-1042/com.example.alan.sunshine I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.content.res.TypedArray.getChangingConfigurations, referenced from method android.support.v7.widget.TintTypedArray.getChangingConfigurations
    06-20 16:19:10.765 1042-1042/com.example.alan.sunshine W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 461: Landroid/content/res/TypedArray;.getChangingConfigurations ()I
    06-20 16:19:10.765 1042-1042/com.example.alan.sunshine D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0002
    06-20 16:19:10.765 1042-1042/com.example.alan.sunshine I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.content.res.TypedArray.getType, referenced from method android.support.v7.widget.TintTypedArray.getType
    06-20 16:19:10.765 1042-1042/com.example.alan.sunshine W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 483: Landroid/content/res/TypedArray;.getType (I)I
    06-20 16:19:10.765 1042-1042/com.example.alan.sunshine D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0008
    06-20 16:19:10.769 1042-1042/com.example.alan.sunshine I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.support.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawableCompat.getLayoutDirection, referenced from method android.support.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawableCompat.needMirroring
    06-20 16:19:10.769 1042-1042/com.example.alan.sunshine W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 2242: Landroid/support/graphics/drawable/VectorDrawableCompat;.getLayoutDirection ()I
    06-20 16:19:10.769 1042-1042/com.example.alan.sunshine D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x000f
    06-20 16:19:10.789 1042-1042/com.example.alan.sunshine I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.view.ViewGroup$MarginLayoutParams.resolveLayoutDirection, referenced from method android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout$LayoutParams.resolveLayoutDirection
    06-20 16:19:10.789 1042-1042/com.example.alan.sunshine W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 16889: Landroid/view/ViewGroup$MarginLayoutParams;.resolveLayoutDirection (I)V
    06-20 16:19:10.789 1042-1042/com.example.alan.sunshine D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6f at 0x0001
    06-20 16:19:10.885 1042-1042/com.example.alan.sunshine I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable, referenced from method android.support.v7.widget.ResourcesWrapper.getDrawable
    06-20 16:19:10.885 1042-1042/com.example.alan.sunshine W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 424: Landroid/content/res/Resources;.getDrawable (ILandroid/content/res/Resources$Theme;)Landroid/graphics/drawable/Drawable;
    06-20 16:19:10.889 1042-1042/com.example.alan.sunshine D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0002
    06-20 16:19:10.941 1042-1042/com.example.alan.sunshine I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.content.res.Resources.getDrawableForDensity, referenced from method android.support.v7.widget.ResourcesWrapper.getDrawableForDensity
    06-20 16:19:10.941 1042-1042/com.example.alan.sunshine W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 426: Landroid/content/res/Resources;.getDrawableForDensity (IILandroid/content/res/Resources$Theme;)Landroid/graphics/drawable/Drawable;
    06-20 16:19:10.941 1042-1042/com.example.alan.sunshine D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0002
    06-20 16:19:10.945 1042-1042/com.example.alan.sunshine I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.content.Context.getColorStateList, referenced from method android.support.v7.content.res.AppCompatResources.getColorStateList
    06-20 16:19:10.949 1042-1042/com.example.alan.sunshine W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 275: Landroid/content/Context;.getColorStateList (I)Landroid/content/res/ColorStateList;
    06-20 16:19:10.949 1042-1042/com.example.alan.sunshine D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0006
    06-20 16:19:10.949 1042-1042/com.example.alan.sunshine W/ResourceType: No package identifier when getting value for resource number 0x00000000
    06-20 16:19:10.949 1042-1042/com.example.alan.sunshine D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
    06-20 16:19:10.949 1042-1042/com.example.alan.sunshine W/dalvikvm: threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xa630c288)
    06-20 16:19:11.129 1042-1042/com.example.alan.sunshine E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                             android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x0
                                                                                 at android.content.res.Resources.getText(Resources.java:229)
                                                                                 at android.support.v7.widget.ResourcesWrapper.getText(ResourcesWrapper.java:52)
                                                                                 at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3620)
                                                                                 at com.example.alan.sunshine.CustomeSwipeAdapter.instantiateItem(CustomeSwipeAdapter.java:39)
                                                                                 at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.addNewItem(ViewPager.java:1034)
                                                                                 at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1182)
                                                                                 at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1116)
                                                                                 at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onMeasure(ViewPager.java:1642)
                                                                                 at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15172)
                                                                                 at android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout.internalMeasureChildren(ConstraintLayout.java:383)
                                                                                 at android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout.onMeasure(ConstraintLayout.java:431)
                                                                                 at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15172)
                                                                                 at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4814)
                                                                                 at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
                                                                                 at android.support.v7.widget.ContentFrameLayout.onMeasure(ContentFrameLayout.java:139)
                                                                                 at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15172)
                                                                                 at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4814)
                                                                                 at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1390)
                                                                                 at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:681)
                                                                                 at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:574)
                                                                                 at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15172)
                                                                                 at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4814)
                                                                                 at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
                                                                                 at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15172)
                                                                                 at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4814)
                                                                                 at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1390)
                                                                                 at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:681)
                                                                                 at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:574)
                                                                                 at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15172)
                                                                                 at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4814)
                                                                                 at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
                                                                                 at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2148)
                                                                                 at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15172)
                                                                                 at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:1848)
                                                                                 at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1100)
                                                                                 at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1273)
                                                                                 at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:998)
                                                                                 at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:4212)
                                                                                 at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:725)
                                                                                 at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:555)
                                                                                 at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:525)
                                                                                 at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:711)
                                                                                 at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
                                                                                 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
                                                                                 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
                                                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                                                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
                                                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
                                                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
                                                                                 at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
    06-20 16:19:11.157 1042-1044/com.example.alan.sunshine D/dalvikvm: GC_CONCURRENT freed 262K, 4% free 8158K/8455K, paused 27ms+1ms, total 52ms
    06-20 16:19:11.161 1042-1042/com.example.alan.sunshine D/dalvikvm: WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 28ms
    06-20 16:19:11.165 370-521/system_process W/ActivityManager:   Force finishing activity com.example.alan.sunshine/.MainActivity
    06-20 16:19:11.217 354-355/? E/SocketStream: readFully was waiting for 403440 bytes, got 16192 
    06-20 16:19:11.217 354-355/? E/SocketStream: readFully was waiting for 387248 bytes, got 16192 
    06-20 16:19:11.217 354-355/? E/SocketStream: readFully was waiting for 371056 bytes, got 16192 
    06-20 16:19:11.221 354-355/? E/SocketStream: readFully was waiting for 354864 bytes, got 16192 
    06-20 16:19:11.221 354-355/? E/SocketStream: readFully was waiting for 338672 bytes, got 16192 
    06-20 16:19:11.221 354-355/? E/SocketStream: readFully was waiting for 322480 bytes, got 16192 
    06-20 16:19:11.221 354-355/? E/SocketStream: readFully was waiting for 306288 bytes, got 16192 
    06-20 16:19:11.221 354-355/? E/SocketStream: readFully was waiting for 290096 bytes, got 16192 
    06-20 16:19:11.221 354-355/? E/SocketStream: readFully was waiting for 273904 bytes, got 16192 
    06-20 16:19:11.221 354-355/? E/SocketStream: readFully was waiting for 257712 bytes, got 9032 
    06-20 16:19:11.225 354-355/? E/SocketStream: readFully was waiting for 248680 bytes, got 16192 
    06-20 16:19:11.229 354-355/? E/SocketStream: readFully was waiting for 232488 bytes, got 16192 
    06-20 16:19:11.229 354-355/? E/SocketStream: readFully was waiting for 216296 bytes, got 16192 
    06-20 16:19:11.229 354-355/? E/SocketStream: readFully was waiting for 200104 bytes, got 16192 
    06-20 16:19:11.229 354-355/? E/SocketStream: readFully was waiting for 183912 bytes, got 16192 
    06-20 16:19:11.229 354-355/? E/SocketStream: readFully was waiting for 167720 bytes, got 16192 
    06-20 16:19:11.229 354-355/? E/SocketStream: readFully was waiting for 151528 bytes, got 16192 
    06-20 16:19:11.229 354-355/? E/SocketStream: readFully was waiting for 135336 bytes, got 16192 
    06-20 16:19:11.229 354-355/? E/SocketStream: readFully was waiting for 119144 bytes, got 16192 
    06-20 16:19:11.229 354-355/? E/SocketStream: readFully was waiting for 102952 bytes, got 14872 
    06-20 16:19:11.229 354-355/? E/SocketStream: readFully was waiting for 88080 bytes, got 16192 
    06-20 16:19:11.229 354-355/? E/SocketStream: readFully was waiting for 71888 bytes, got 16192 
    06-20 16:19:11.229 354-355/? E/SocketStream: readFully was waiting for 55696 bytes, got 16192 
    06-20 16:19:11.229 354-355/? E/SocketStream: readFully was waiting for 39504 bytes, got 16192 
    06-20 16:19:11.229 354-355/? E/SocketStream: readFully was waiting for 23312 bytes, got 16192 
    06-20 16:19:11.261 370-521/system_process D/dalvikvm: GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 82K, 10% free 10605K/11783K, paused 24ms, total 24ms
    06-20 16:19:11.265 370-521/system_process I/dalvikvm-heap: Grow heap (frag case) to 10.596MB for 214524-byte allocation
    06-20 16:19:11.317 370-521/system_process D/dalvikvm: GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 2K, 11% free 10812K/12039K, paused 53ms, total 53ms

                                                          [ 06-20 16:19:11.533   370:  384 D/         ]
                                                          HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xb939dcb0, tid 384
    06-20 16:19:11.825 370-383/system_process W/ActivityManager: Activity pause timeout for ActivityRecord{536c44a8 com.example.alan.sunshine/.MainActivity}
    06-20 16:19:11.905 524-524/com.android.launcher W/EGL_genymotion: eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
    06-20 16:19:11.925 524-524/com.android.launcher D/OpenGLRenderer: TextureCache::get: create texture(0xb91dfd50): name, size, mSize = 34, 324, 727572
    06-20 16:19:11.925 524-524/com.android.launcher D/OpenGLRenderer: TextureCache::get: create texture(0xb9231988): name, size, mSize = 35, 324, 727896
    06-20 16:19:11.933 524-524/com.android.launcher D/OpenGLRenderer: TextureCache::get: create texture(0xb91f0950): name, size, mSize = 36, 20736, 748632
    06-20 16:19:11.937 524-524/com.android.launcher D/OpenGLRenderer: TextureCache::get: create texture(0xb92139d0): name, size, mSize = 37, 20736, 769368
    06-20 16:19:11.953 524-524/com.android.launcher D/OpenGLRenderer: TextureCache::get: create texture(0xb922a0f8): name, size, mSize = 39, 20736, 790104
    06-20 16:19:11.953 524-524/com.android.launcher D/OpenGLRenderer: TextureCache::get: create texture(0xb9224c00): name, size, mSize = 40, 20736, 810840
    06-20 16:19:11.957 524-524/com.android.launcher D/OpenGLRenderer: TextureCache::get: create texture(0xb91e8420): name, size, mSize = 41, 20736, 831576
    06-20 16:19:11.961 524-524/com.android.launcher D/OpenGLRenderer: TextureCache::get: create texture(0xb91e7cd0): name, size, mSize = 42, 20736, 852312
    06-20 16:19:11.977 524-524/com.android.launcher D/OpenGLRenderer: TextureCache::get: create texture(0xb92c29d0): name, size, mSize = 43, 345744, 1198056
    06-20 16:19:12.033 370-427/system_process I/qtaguid: Failed write_ctrl(s 0 10048) res=-1 errno=1
    06-20 16:19:12.033 370-381/system_process I/ActivityManager: No longer want com.android.mms (pid 838): hidden #16
    06-20 16:19:12.037 370-427/system_process W/NetworkManagementSocketTagger: setKernelCountSet(10048, 0) failed with errno -1
    06-20 16:19:12.037 370-370/system_process D/CountryDetector: No listener is left
    06-20 16:19:17.653 370-381/system_process I/ActivityManager: No longer want com.android.settings (pid 542): hidden #16
    06-20 16:19:19.541 1042-1042/com.example.alan.sunshine I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 1042 SIG: 9
    06-20 16:19:19.553 169-283/? I/AudioMixer: found effect "Multichannel Downmix To Stereo" from The Android Open Source Project
    06-20 16:19:19.557 169-283/? W/genymotion_audio: out_write() limiting sleep time 46802 to 39909
    06-20 16:19:19.557 370-522/system_process I/WindowState: WIN DEATH: Window{5369be38 com.example.alan.sunshine/com.example.alan.sunshine.MainActivity paused=false}
    06-20 16:19:19.561 370-370/system_process I/ActivityManager: Process com.example.alan.sunshine (pid 1042) has died.
    06-20 16:19:19.601 370-381/system_process W/InputMethodManagerService: Window already focused, ignoring focus gain of: com.android.internal.view.IInputMethodClient$Stub$Proxy@535fb5f4 attribute=null
    06-20 16:19:19.637 169-283/? W/genymotion_audio: out_write() limiting sleep time 58911 to 39909
    06-20 16:19:19.677 169-283/? W/genymotion_audio: out_write() limiting sleep time 59182 to 39909
    06-20 16:19:22.033 370-383/system_process W/ActivityManager: Activity destroy timeout for ActivityRecord{536c44a8 com.example.alan.sunshine/.MainActivity}
    06-20 16:19:23.413 56-56/? W/Genyd: Can't parse request
    06-20 16:19:23.465 56-56/? W/Genyd: Can't parse request
    06-20 16:19:23.465 56-56/? W/Genyd: Can't parse request
    06-20 16:19:23.465 56-56/? W/Genyd: Can't parse request
    06-20 16:19:23.473 56-56/? W/Genyd: Can't parse request
    06-20 16:19:23.473 56-56/? W/Genyd: Can't parse request
    06-20 16:19:23.473 56-56/? W/Genyd: Can't parse request
    06-20 16:19:23.481 56-56/? W/Genyd: Can't parse request
    06-20 16:19:23.481 56-56/? W/Genyd: Can't parse request
    06-20 16:19:23.481 56-56/? W/Genyd: Can't parse request
    06-20 16:19:23.489 56-56/? W/Genyd: Can't parse request
    06-20 16:19:23.489 56-56/? D/Genyd: Received Set Clipboard
    06-20 16:19:23.493 56-56/? D/Genymotion: Received Set Clipboard
    06-20 16:19:23.569 370-444/system_process I/ClipboardService: Got clipboard for user=0
    06-20 16:19:23.569 370-444/system_process I/ClipboardService: Got clipboard for user=0
    06-20 16:19:23.581 370-383/system_process I/ClipboardService: Got clipboard for user=0
    06-20 16:19:23.581 370-383/system_process I/ClipboardService: Got clipboard for user=0
    06-20 16:19:23.581 370-383/system_process I/ClipboardService: Got clipboard for user=0
```

Comment: Your error is at `(CustomeSwipeAdapter.java:39)`. Read the duplicates

Comment: how can i fix it

Comment: ok  i got  i am passing int value